# HTML : Make <object> a link

Tags: html, flash, hyperlink

I have HTML code I got from a designer of the form:

```
    <object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=5,0,0,0" width="100" height="20">
      <param name="movie" value="PRODUCTS.swf" />
      <param name="quality" value="high" />
      <param name="bgcolor" value="#FFFFFF" />
      <embed src="PRODUCTS.swf" quality="high" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/shockwave/download/index.cgi?P1_Prod_Version=ShockwaveFlash" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="100" height="20" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"></embed> 
    </object>
```

I want to turn it into a link, so when I click it it will go to `./Products.html` can't figure out how.
I wrapped entire `object` into `<a href...></a>` but when I click it, it gives me warning about going through Internet, and doesn't change the page.

I have very little understanding of *Flash*. This is probably trivial, but I can't find right answer.

*Note:* I could get more info from the designer, but loosing that flash is also acceptable.

Comment: hey dude, ever since your legendary "Chuck Norris" comment at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454 , I've wanted a better description of who you are. Update your profile!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not as easy as one would think. When you click inside the Flash movie, that click will be captured by the movie and not the surrounding HTML document. That means that any element you put around the movie will not have any effect. (No reliable cross-browser effect, anyway.)

The simplest way would be having the Flash designer add a invisible link element to the movie.

The second simplest way I can think of is making the movie `wmode=transparent` and overlaying it with an invisible `<a>` element. But that is already horribly complicated, depends on Flash versions, how the movie is compiled, and so on.

Best talk to the designer and have him/her change the movie.